# How to scroll page up/down using Selenium Driver in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, scroll, automated-tests

I am trying to scroll my window up in automated testing environment, but this just does not work (also no errors in console):

```
public void ScrollToTheTop()
{
    if (this.driver is RemoteWebDriver remoteDriver)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor jex = remoteDriver;
        jex.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0,0)");
    }
}
```

Now if I try to execute `jex.ExecuteScript("alert('Something')")` it works fine, which means that js gets executed correctly. But for some reason scroll operations do not work (tried `scrollBy()` aswell).

Does anybody know how to execute scroll scripts? Thank you.

Comment: Does not answer my question but that's one workaround I found to click elements that are not visible:
````((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
````

element is of type ````IWebElement````

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll in C#, Using ExecuteScript please use below code :

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, Y)");
```

Where `Y` should be vertical axis.

to scroll down :

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, 200)");
```

or to scroll up :

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, -200)");
```

To move to a specific web element in **C#-Selenium bindings**  :

```
IWebElement e = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath of the web element));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", e);
```

to move till end of the page :

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;");
```

Comment: Thanks for the code examples, but if you look closely, you would see, that my code is almost identical, yet it does not work. The problem is that the window scroll script does not have any effect on the page.

Comment: You've something called `RemoteWebDriver` I believe it's parent class of webdriver. Did you try all of them and nothing worked  ?

Comment: it is the parent class of all the different drivers (Chrome, Firefox etc). As I said, it does the job, I've tested it with `alert( )` script and it is executed correctly. For some reason scrolling scripts have no effect though.